# cumulative likes per week for facebook page Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the cumulative number of likes per week(more specifically the last 7 days) for any given date. Is there any FB Graph API call for this data?

I tried using the endpoints 
'{fb-pagename}/?summary=true'
and
'{fb-pagename}/likes/?summary=true'.

Through the first one I get a lifetime likes count. The second one should produce something similar, but only the names of the users that liked the page are returned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if you're the owner of the specifiy Page (because of the necessary `read_insights` permission) via Insights.

```
GET /v2.2/{page-id}/insights/page_fan_adds
```

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/insights/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/insights#page_users

If you aren't the owner of the page, the only thing you can do is to request the public page information recurrently (every 7 days in your example) and query for the likes and calculate the like change amount yourself:

```
GET /v2.2/{page-id}?fields=id,name,likes
```